# Item is losing name while yielding in Python / Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

In Scrapy 2.4.x on Python 3.8.x I am yielding an item with the purpose to save some stats to a DB. The scraper has another Item that gets yielded as well.

While the name of the item is present in the main script "StatsItem", it is lost within the other class. I am using the name of the item to decide which method to call:

in scraper.py:

```
import scrapy
from crawler.items import StatsItem, OtherItem

class demo(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse_item(self, response):
       stats = StatsItem()
       stats['results'] = 10
       yield stats

       print(type(stats).__name__)
       # Output: StatsItem

       print(stats)
       # Output: {'results': 10}
```

in pipeline.py

```
import scrapy
from crawler.items import StatsItem, OtherItem

class mysql_pipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        print(type(item).__name__)
        # Output: NoneType

        if isinstance(item, StatsItem):
            self.save_stats(item, spider)

        elif isinstance(item, OtherItem):
            # call other method

        return item
```

The output of print in the first class is "StatsItem", while it is "NoneType" within the pipeline, therefore the method save_stats() gets never called.

I am pretty new to Python, so there might be a better way of doing this. There is no error message or exception I am aware of. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only object that has the type `NoneType` is `None`. Thus, it's not just the name being lost -- you don't have the value at all.

Comment: You don't need to inherited from `(object)` (that's implicit, you can leave it off). And if you're getting `NoneType` as the name of the type, that means your function is being called with `item` being `None`. As you're not including the call it's impossible to say why that is, or whether it's even surprising.

Comment: This is totaly strange. I have a similar crawler where the copy/paste code works. There is no difference I can see. Also the item is empty when I print it out inside process item, however it is not empty in the method "demo". I get a print out of the dictionary and the class name.

Comment: is this really works? it should gives you error message because `yield` can't be directly in `class`. It has to be in some method - ie. in method `parse`. With current code we can't reproduce problem. You may create minimal working code with your problem which we could simply copy and run and see problem.

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Taceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: You didn't show full error message which could better explain problem. I tried to build working code and I have some problem with `None` only when there is no `return item` in `process_item`

Comment: @furas There is no error message. I edited the question and added the value of each item at both states. The item is simply empty when passed into the other class. As I said I have this code in operation at another spider and it works just fine. Difficult to debug, any suggestions? (it is inside parse_item, edited question)

Comment: you still don't have `return item` in `def process_item` - so it can send `None` to other `pipeline` and it can makes problem. OR maybe you forgot `return item` in other `pipeline` and now you don't get item in this `pipeline`. Better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run. I made own code and it doesn't have this problem - but I don't know if you don't use other elements or pipeline which could remove it.

Comment: @furas I found the problem and posted an answer. Thank you for your help looking into this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `yield` outside of a function imo.

Answer (score 0):

I was finaly able to locate the problem. The particular crawler was nearly identical to all other ones that did not have this issue but with one exception, I was custom setting the item pipeline:

```
custom_settings.update({
    'ITEM_PIPELINES' : {
         'crawler.pipelines.mysql_pipeline': 301,
     }
})
```

Removing this, fixed the issue.

Comment: if you remove it then it should run crawler without running `mysql_pipeline`

Comment: That is exactly the point, the pipeline was imported twice. Once inside settings.py and once through updating the settings directly within the crawler. This has caused this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: the same `pipeline` in two places - this is unusual situation which can make problem to find solution :)